# Do different locks cover each other?

Tags: kotlin, synchronization, locking

I would like to ask about locking mechanism. Lets say I want to do something like "very simple databse". I have 3 maps, one for storing values and two others for storing indices "by user" and "by device", so that filtering by both is more effective. I don't want to have inconsistencies across these three maps, as almost all methods are manipulating with 2 or all maps so synchronization is required and Concurrent map types are not enough.

Question: Is it okey to mix synchronized(this) together with synchronized(userIdIndices) or I need to use *this* everywhere?. If a thread enters for example *addDataPoint()* method, would synchronized(this) also lock *getUserIdIndicesSize()* synchronized(userIdIndices) as lets say some higher order lock or these are totally independent locks and it would enable concurrent access.

```
@Component
class DatapointStore {
    private val dataPoints = HashMap<DatapointKey, Double>()
    private val userIdIndices = HashMap<Long, TreeSet<DatapointKey>>()
    private val deviceIdIndices = HashMap<Long, TreeSet<DatapointKey>>()

    fun getDataPointsSize() = synchronized(dataPoints) { dataPoints.size }
    fun getUserIdIndicesSize() = synchronized(userIdIndices) { userIdIndices.size }
    fun getDeviceIdIndicesSize() = synchronized(deviceIdIndices) { deviceIdIndices.size }

    fun addDataPoint(dataPoint: DatapointRequest) {
        synchronized(this) { ... }
    }

    fun filterByUserId(userId: Long): List<DatapointRequest> {
        synchronized(this) { ... }
    }

    fun filterByDeviceId(deviceId: Long): List<DatapointRequest> {
        synchronized(this) { ... }
    }

    fun deleteByUserId(userId: Long) {
        synchronized(this) { ... }
    }

    fun deleteByDeviceId(deviceId: Long) {
        synchronized(this) { ... }
    }
}
```

I expect it to be fully synchronized, where one thread can not add new datapoint while other is deleting, filtering or checking size, but I would not mind checking *getUserIdIndicesSize()* while executing *filterByDeviceId()*.  That is why I want to mix two types of locks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no relationship between two object mutexes. The lock represented by `synchronized(this)` is a separate and independent lock from the one created by `synchronized(dataPoints)`, even when `dataPoints` is a property of `this`. If you want atomic updates across all three of your maps, you'll need to use a single shared mutex (like `this`) to access them all.